# sharedpreferences with expiration date

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

is it possible to have put a sharedpreferences key with an expiration date?

For example, if i need to save the users id number, but i want it to be "forgotten" a day later...

today i use the key of the string for this purpose: when i save the string i set the key to be "id_", and when my app starts i go over all of my preferences keys (getAll()) and seek a key that starts with "id_", Then i parse the trailing date to find out if i need to keep it or not.

is there a better way?

Comment: I'd say including the date / time when you store it and then parsing it when you retrieve it should be easy enough and work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store two preferences: one for the value and another specifying its expiration. For example:

```
long expires = prefs.getLong("id_expiration", 0);
if(System.currentTimeMillis() < expires){
    //still valid
    String id = prefs.getString("id_value", "");
}
```

Alternatively, if your preference value will always have a known format, you could concatenate the value & expiration into one string and store it. For example:

```
String[] id = prefs.getString("id", "0:0").split(":");
if(id.length == 2 && System.currentTimeMillis() < Long.parseLong(id[1])){
    //still valid
    String id_value = id[0];
}
```

And finally, you could use an object that implements Serializable, or alternatively use JSON, and write it to a string pref.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no direct way to get Android to clean up your preferences for you. What you could do, though, is include a date in your preference that you store. For example, if you wanted to store a JSON object, you could store:

```
{
   value: 'xxx',
   expiration: 'yyyy-dd-mm'
}
```

Then parse the date after you retrieve the object from preferences:

```
String json = prefs.getString(id);
try {
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
  String date = obj.getString("expiration");
  // Parse the date string and check to make sure it isn't expired.
} catch (JSONException e) {
  // Handle exception
}
```